# Statistics Marble Simulation

Tags: statistics, simulation

Given the jar containing 20 red, 5 white, and 10 blue marbles, Joey thinks a more interesting problem would be to find the number of marbles you would have to draw, without replacing them in the jar, to be sure that you have 2 red marbles.

Design and carry out a simulation to determine the number of marbles you would have to draw, with replacement, until you get 2 red marbles.  Compare the results from your simulation with the results from the previous exercise.

Would I simply use Table B to find out, of 35 trials, how many times I get a number less than 5, or something like that?  I know how simulations work I just can't really remember how to design/come up with one for this.

Comment: It's asking "How many marbles do you expect to draw before drawing 2 red marbles?" The keyword here would be *expect*.